# how do I make $.ajax POST call to work with SSL?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ssl, post

Here is my JavaScript:

```
parameter = "name=" + name + "&email=" +
  email + "&phone=" + phone + "&comments=" + comments;

$.ajax({
  url: 'sendEmail.php?' + parameter,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.indexOf("Message sent") > 0) {
      alert("Your email has been sent.");
      $('#user-name' + id).val("");
      $('#user-phone' + id).val("");
      $('#user-email' + id).val("");
      $('#user-message' + id).val("");
    } else {
      alert("Your email could not be sent!")
      console.log(data);
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert("Email could not be sent!")
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

And here is my `sendMail.php`

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

var_dump($_POST); echo "\n";
```

Why does this `var_dump()` return `null`?
This only since I added SSL to the domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var parameter = {
 name: name, 
 email:email, 
 phone: phone,
 comments: comments
};
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "sendEmail.php",
      data:parameter, 
      method:"POST",
      async:true,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.indexOf("Message sent") > 0) {
          alert("Your email has been sent.");
          $('#user-name' + id).val("");
          $('#user-phone' + id).val("");
          $('#user-email' + id).val("");
          $('#user-message' + id).val("");
        } else {
          alert("Your email could not be sent!")
          console.log(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks so much.  this fixed the issue.  not sure what was wrong with my .AJAX call but now my POST data gets into the sendEmail.php.

Comment: so my PHP code to send email works if I use my laptop/chrome

Comment: using my android phone also chrome i Get the alert("Email could not be sent!"- any idea on this???

Comment: try catch the error on event >    
error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
alert(status);
    }

Comment: so now i moved my code/webside to a new server...same code that worked on the old server now it errors out it gets to the alert("Email could not be sent!") . never gets into sendEmail.php! any idea on this? firewall?

Comment: I modify the error function parameters. try catch the error.

Comment: i have:   error: function (request, status, error) { 
   alert(error); alert(status); alert("Email could not be sent!");

Comment: it returns: "server error", "error", "Email could not be sent!" - does not help me ,,, any further ideas?

Comment: request.status ?

Comment: debuging the js

Comment: Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions   another clue

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting to your script, you are using the URL query. You need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a GET request, but you want to take data from POST.
send data with post

```
$.post('sendEmail.php', {'name':name,'email':email,'phone':phone,'comments':comments}, function(data){
    if (data.indexOf("Message sent") > 0) {
      alert("Your email has been sent.");
      $('#user-name' + id).val("");
      $('#user-phone' + id).val("");
      $('#user-email' + id).val("");
      $('#user-message' + id).val("");
    } else {
      alert("Your email could not be sent!")
      console.log(data);
    }
})
```